# how to remove elbow-line of all last visible child after filtering tree in extjs

Tags: extjs, tree, treepanel

[treepanel_elbow_line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9okop.png)

I want to remove last visible child elbow lines (shown in image with red rectangle) of the tree panel after filtering/searching tree.

Comment: Looks like a bug, why not to disable lines altogether   lines:false

Comment: @FabioBarros that is my boss's wish.

Comment: What version of ExtJS are you using?

Comment: @scebotari66 Extjs version : "5.1.0.107"